# Horizontal position of two cells returns same result for cells in different columns in Word VSTO

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

[image]I compared results of reading (x,y) coordinates of different cells for two different tables. For one, works perfectly fine - both x and y are correctly read, whereas for the second, x should be different but is the same for two cells. I am sure that I chose correct cells because their text is correct (also their height and width). Both tables have no empty cells and the indexes are correct. I've also tried the approach with selecting cell via **Cell.Select()** and then reading the vertical/horizontal position from selected range. The result's the same.

Code reading vertical and horizontal position of cell (for different values of index):

```
private ResultObject CreateresultObjectBasedOnTable(Table table, int cellIndex)
{
    var resultObject = new ResultObject();

    double DPIMultiplier = 200.0 / 220.0;

    resultObject.y = table.Range.Cells[cellIndex].Range.
        Information[WdInformation.wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage] * DPIMultiplier;
    resultObject.x = table.Range.Cells[cellIndex].Range.
        Information[WdInformation.wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage] * DPIMultiplier;

    resultObject.Height = table.Range.Cells[cellIndex].Height * DPIMultiplier;
    resultObject.Width = table.Range.Cells[cellIndex].Width * DPIMultiplier;

    return resultObject;
}
```

For first table in the attached picture, for cellIndex = 1, cellIndex = 2 and cellIndex = 3, the results vary. For the second table for cellIndex = 1, cellIndex = 2 and cellIndex = 3 resultObject.x is the same.

Comment: Please provide a full [mcve], including creating the document with the tables. A couple of screen shots wouldn't hurt, either. FWIW is the problem table "floating" or in a textbox or similar?

Comment: I posted changes. The table's floating for both tables. Also, cell's content is different in the original document but I had to change it due to confidentiality of the data.

Comment: I'm currently on a mobile device so can't do any testing, immediately, but... One problem could be the *merged cells*. Another could be the "floating". HOW are they "floated"? Using what commands? And see what difference it makes if they're un-floated. Also, is it absolutely necessary to "float" them?

Comment: By floating you mean that the text outside of the table is placed around it? As far as merged cells are concerned, the first table was created as 2 rows by 4 columns and all bottom cells were merged. Could it possibly cause a problem? Should I create the table in a different manner to make the code functional? If so, how should I do it?

Comment: Before anyone can advise on what needs to be changed, it's necessary to figure out where the problem is. Based on my experience and looking that information, either of those things *could* be the problem. In your first comment you say both tables are floating... By floating, I mean that when you look at a table's properties in the Word UI "Text wrapping" is set to "Around" (even if the table is so wide that no text is next to it).